# Printing multiple JOptionPane string input dialogs in one sentence

Tags: java

I want to read input from multiple JOptionPane input dialogs and print the input from each dialog in a JOptionPane Message Dialog in once sentence. For example:
This, is, a, message.

would output as: This is a message

Here is my code which I am trying to adapt, it currently calculates the total amount of characters in all of the inputs.

```
  // A Java Program by Gavin Coll 15306076 to count the total number of characters in words entered by a user //
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WordsLength    
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String words = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your word: "); // Getting the first word

    int length = words.length(); 

    int totallength = length; 
    int secondaryLength;

    do 
    {
        String newwords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter another word: (Enter nothing to stop entering words) "); // Getting more words
        secondaryLength = newwords.length(); // Getting the length of the new words

        totallength += secondaryLength; // Adding the new length to the total length

    } 

    while(secondaryLength != 0);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total number of characters in those words is: " + totallength);

    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate each new word.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class WordsLength {
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            String words = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your word: "); // Getting the first word

            int length = words.length();

            int secondaryLength;
            int totallength = length; 

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(words);

            do {
                String newwords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Enter another word: (Enter nothing to stop entering words) "); // Getting more words

                secondaryLength = newwords.length(); // Getting the length of the new words

                totallength += secondaryLength; // Adding the new length to the total length

                builder.append(' ');
                builder.append(newwords);

            }

            while (secondaryLength != 0);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total number of characters in those words is : " + totallength);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The full sentence is : " + builder);

            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```